# Understanding a Topological proof of the infinity of primes

Tags: general-topology, number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-explanation

Sorry if the question is too basic, I haven't taken any Topology lectures.

I found this proof in "Proofs from THE BOOK" and don't quite understand the explanation of why **$ N_{a,b} $** is closed, I hope you could spell it out for me.

Thank you in advance.

[image: Proofs from THE BOOK - Fifth Proof of the infinity of primes]

Comment: $N_{a,b}$ is the complement of a union of open sets; a union of open sets is open, and the complement of an open set is closed; see also [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furstenberg%27s_proof_of_the_infinitude_of_primes)

Comment: But why $ N_{a,b} $ is closed and each $ N_{a+i,b} $ would be open ?

Comment: actually each $N_{a,b}$ is open and closed in this topology

Comment: Thank you @J.W.Tanner, I think I get it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any topology, a union of open sets is open.

In this topology, each $N_{a+i,b}$ is open, so $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{b-1} N_{a+i,b}$ is open.

In any topology, the complement of an open set is closed.

Therefore, $N_{a,b}=\Bbb Z\setminus \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{b-1} N_{a+i,b}$ is closed.

(In fact, $N_{a,b}$ is both open and closed -- called clopen -- in this topology.)